# Where is the recursion in this code?

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm studying Scheme by myself and recently I've encountered this code:

```
((lambda (gcd) (gcd (12 8 gcd))
    (lambda(a b gcdnew)
        (if (= b 0)
        a
        (gcdnew b (modulo a b) gcdnew))))
```

The author said there is a recursion in this one. It was an old topic so I couldn't contact him. So where is it (=recursion)? It seems that the second 'lambda' goes to first 'gcd' as value so our body is actually:

```
(gcdnew 8 4 gcdnew)
```

Well, what's the point of 'gcdnew' as a parameter in 'gcdnew'? Thanks for help.

Comment: It's a roundabout way to do recursion without using letrec. Indeed, the extra gcdnew argument is what enables it.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `gcdnew` is that it holds the function to use for the recursive call.

The outer lambda sets the recursion up by taking a function (`gcd`) and applying it to 12 and 8, and also passing *that same function* as a third parameter.
Inside the inner function, `gcdnew` refers to the inner function itself, and it calls itself recursively by using `gcdnew`, making sure to pass it (i.e. itself) along in the recursion.

BTW: There's a slight typo in that you have too many brackets - it should probably be

```
((lambda (gcd) (gcd 12 8 gcd))
   (lambda (a b gcdnew)
     (if (= b 0)
          a
         (gcdnew b (modulo a b) gcdnew))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I did this thing in order to understand how it works:

    (define ama (lambda (a b gcdnew)
     (if (= b 0)
          a
         (gcdnew b (modulo a b) gcdnew))))

and then I did this:

    (ama 12 8 ama)
it allowed me to understand better the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the Y combinator.

And it's actually possible to do recursion with it in languages that don't support explicit recursion. (in fact you don't even need to define it recursivly)

http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2700.html